# What are the "roles of QA in SDLC"

Tags: qa-role

I am having trouble understanding the role of QA in earlier phases of the SDLC.

The role of QA is obvious in the testing phase, but I can not see how QA should participate before that, especially in the planning, designing, or implementation phases.

Comment: You might find this answer somewhat helpful to give you some ideas: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12641/apart-from-testing-and-finding-good-bugs-what-other-things-the-testers-can-do/12642#12642

Comment: We are here not to google for it you. Do your own research and ask clarifying questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apart from testing and finding good bugs what other things the testers can do?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12641/apart-from-testing-and-finding-good-bugs-what-other-things-the-testers-can-do)

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a role for QA and, in my experience, makes quality more effective as a while when QA is involved the planning, designing and implementation phases.

Typically, in the design, planning and implementation phases, QA can/should be:

- Creating a comprehensive test strategy for the feature/enhancement (identifying user scenarios, edge cases, data requirements, etc)
- Outlining feature acceptance criteria and critical path scenarios with Product Management and Engineering
- Pushing quality process and best practices with PM and Engineering
- Collaborating with other stakeholders (Support and Consulting teams) to ensure that as many test scenarios are included in the strategy as possible
- Learning the implementations (technical implementations) engineering will put in place to ensure system testing is done where needed